How can I set Go's log/slog to send to multiple outputs (console, file) and in different formats (TextHandler, JSONHandler)?
When I create a slog instance I need to pass a single slog.Handler to that means that a logger can only write to a single Handler and the handlers that come with slog seem to write to a single output and format.
Is there any handler, in stdlib or elsewhere that provides copies / retransmites to multiple outputs:
I'm after something like this
var logger = slog.New(NewCopyHandler(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil), slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, nil))) 
logger.Info("mytest", "attr1", "value1", "attr2", "value2")


that will produce something like this:
time=2024-12-06T12:18:34.454+01:00 level=INFO msg=test attr1=value1 attr2=value2
{"time":"2024-12-06T12:18:34.454274+01:00","level":"INFO","msg":"test","attr1":"value1","attr2":"value2"}


I don't think there is anything like that in Go's stdlib. But slog-multi has a Fanout handler that does exactly that.
logger = slog.New(slogmulti.Fanout(
    slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil),
    slog.NewJSONHandler(f, nil),
))


But it's relatively easy to write your own handler:
type CopyHandler struct {
    mu *sync.Mutex
    out []slog.Handler // all the destinations
}


func NewCopyHandler(handlers ...slog.Handler) *CopyHandler {
    h := &CopyHandler{out: handlers, mu: &sync.Mutex{}}
    return h
}

func (h *CopyHandler) Enabled(ctx context.Context, level slog.Level) bool {
    // leave the enable check to the underlying handlers
    return true
}

func (h *CopyHandler) Handle(ctx context.Context, r slog.Record) error {
    h.mu.Lock()
    defer h.mu.Unlock()
    for _, destHandler := range h.out {
    err := destHandler.Handle(ctx, r)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }
    return nil
}


func (h *CopyHandler) WithGroup(name string) slog.Handler {
    // call WithGroup on the underlying handlers
    // we should not make modification the receiver, we return a copy
    if name == "" {
        return h
    }
    h2:=*h
    h2.out = make([]slog.Handler, len(h.out))
    for i, h := range h.out {
    h2.out[i] = h.WithGroup(name)
  }
  return &h2
}


func (h *CopyHandler) WithAttrs(attrs []slog.Attr) slog.Handler {
    // call WithAttrs on the underlying handlers
    // we should not make modification the receiver, we return a copy
    if (len(attrs) == 0) {
       return h
    }
    h2 := *h
    h2.out = make([]slog.Handler, len(h.out))
    for i, h := range h.out {
        h2.out[i] = h.WithAttrs(attrs)
    }
    return &h2
}

with that handler you can do:
var logger = slog.New(NewCopyHandler(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil), slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, nil)))
logger.Info("test", "attr1", "value1", "attr2", "value2")


and you will obtain the desired:
time=2024-12-06T12:27:46.066+01:00 level=INFO msg=test attr1=value1 attr2=value2
{"time":"2024-12-06T12:27:46.066806+01:00","level":"INFO","msg":"test","attr1":"value1","attr2":"value2"}

The example above send both text and json to stdout but you can of course send the ld-json to a file instead:
f,err :=  os.OpenFile("log.json", os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
}
logger = slog.New(NewCopyHandler(slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stdout, nil), slog.NewJSONHandler(f, nil)))


